# Unable to render XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

Im trying to use the [SlidingPanel library by Umano](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel). While the DemoApp compiles and runs fine. It doesnt render the XML.

Here's the exception that the XML displays while rendering:
http://pastebin.com/TZ2iSydg

**activity_demo.xml**

```
   <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DemoActivity" >

    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.demo.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:dragView="@+id/name"
        sothree:panelHeight="68dp"
        sothree:paralaxOffset="100dp"
        sothree:shadowHeight="4dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Main Content"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#eeeeee"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="68dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/follow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:src="@drawable/graphic" >
            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.demo.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: 1) you should put that pastebin in the question. 2) It looks like a 'normal' custom view doesn't show up in eclipse xml viewer. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743030/custom-android-views-in-eclipse-visual-editor

Answer (score 0):

Custom `Views` usually don't render in the UI editor in Eclipse or IntelliJ. It's not tragic.

The stack trace however suggests that you should use `View.isInEditMode()` to skip the rendering if the custom `View` is just being displayed in the UI editor.

You can just add this:

```
if(isInEditMode()){
    return;
}
```

after [this](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/master/library/src/com/sothree/slidinguppanel/SlidingUpPanelLayout.java#L257) line in the custom `View`, if you're using a local copy of the library. Or just send a pull request to the repo on Github, that adds that.

Comment: that returns an error. "The blank final field mShadowDrawable may not have been initialized" mShadowDrawable is a drawable

Comment: @alexsummers That's not an error that's juts a warning. You can safely ignore that.

Comment: nah, still doesnt render.

Comment: @alexsummers It won't render. The UI editor in Eclipse and IntelliJ is not laid out to render complex custom Views. These 2 lines however prevent the UI editor to spit out these warnings that the custom View can't be rendered.

Comment: oh. Should be an online app of some sort where you paste your java+xml and it lets your create your custom view and edit it