# How to check, if `onDraw` is called in preview mode

Tags: android, android-studio, drawing

In my custom-drawn view I use the `Canvas.drawPaint(Paint)` method. But the preview in Android Studio displays this message:

```
The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate: 
    - Canvas.drawPaint is not supported
```

It's easy to replace `drawPaint` with `drawRect`, but the javadoc to `drawPaint` says: *This is equivalent (but faster) to drawing an infinitely large rectangle with the specified paint.*

My question is: can I check, if I'm drawing in preview mode, and conditionally use either method? Or some other workaround to make preview working and keep the performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use View's built-in `isInEditMode()` function as documented here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isInEditMode%28%29

You can also find other methods in this thread:
[Custom Android Views in Eclipse Visual Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743030/custom-android-views-in-eclipse-visual-editor)

Good luck!